git: best way to merge master to my branch
Here is git workflow at my work:

pull remote in master
create a branch and finish work on it
commit and push
finally gets merged to remote

Now I have been asked to always merge latest to my branch master before pushing so that I have latest fixes for flaky tests etc and it could have been days since I merged master (step #1). So this is what I am doing, which sounds sub-optimal to say the least:

pull remote in master
create a branch and finish work on it
commit and push
immediately switch to master branch and again pull remote
merge master to my branch
push again
finally gets merged to remote

Is there a better way to do this please. What I'm doing can't the best practice?!

We rebase our branch from master before merging into master

@Justinas, sorry dont follow - which step do you do differently, if you can point referencing to my list please

The second half of your step 3, i.e. the "and push", seems unnecessary. That said, pulling in random states of the master branch into a feature branch is not a workflow that I would endorse.

@user2696565 Steps 5 and 6

@j6t, so you mean I could just commit my work in #3 (without pushing) and then merge master and then do one single push?

@user2696565 Yes. Why would you think it is necessary to push an unfinished branch? (By "finished" I mean that step 5 has been completed as required by your supervisors.)

@j6t, apologies I'm still learning and thanks for helping.
